# Can I use frozen fish in a fish pie suitable for home freezing?

Tags: food-safety, freezing, fish, dairy

In the UK (and probably elsewhere), frozen fish is considerably cheaper and more common than fresh fish. In an ideal world, I would use fresh fish along with a cream or milk based bechamel sauce, spinach, cheese and potatoes then freeze any leftovers, but this is really expensive. How would a reheated frozen dish using fresh fish compare with one made using frozen fish? Assuming there are no intrinsic food safety issues associated with this practice, would the quality of the dish suffer from using frozen fish that was reheated twice? I've heard that most "Fresh" fish in UK supermarkets was already pre-frozen then defrosted, which would make it pointless purchasing it specifically for this dish.

Comment: I live in the US; here fish has to be labelled as to whether it was defrosted at the market.  According to what I can find online, it does in the UK as well.  No?

Comment: I've not seen anything obvious like that @FuzzyChef, but it may be in the small print somewhere. With the premium prices charged, my guess is that they won't want to advertise that fact too clearly.

Comment: Ah, here fish markets have to have "previously frozen" clearly marked next to the price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question needs clarifying, and better limited to a single question. However, freezing and thawing, repeatedly, particularly with fish, generally impacts texture in a negative way.  There is not safety issue, per se.  Given your preparation, you might not be too concerned about the texture, but that is probably the main issue.

Comment: Thank you @moscafj. I was thinking more along the lines of what ingredients (or techniques) would freeze best, last longest and be closest to a "Gold standard" FP made with 100% fresh ingredients. If the "Fresh" fish is already frozen, there seems little point in paying a premium for the supermarket doing it!

Comment: Suffice it to say that if you want "100% gold standard fish pie made with 100% fresh ingredients", well, then twice re-frozen products will likely let you down.